# add background image using CSS?

Tags: css, background-image

I am creating a web page and I want to add a background image using CSS. When I added a background image it did not work.

It's in my file directory at folder name Source

css file

> Source/assets/css/style.css

my image at

> Source/assets/img/header.png

and this my html address

> Source/index.html

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="mainheader">
        <nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div><!-- mainheader-->
</div><!-- container -->
```

**CSS**

```
.mainheader {
margin: 0 auto;
background:url(assets/img/header.png);
```

Comment: `background:url(../img/header.png);`

Comment: try `background:url('/assets/img/header.png')` ?

Comment: You are missing a closing `nav` tag

Answer (score 0):

Your background imagepath error

It should be

```
background:url(../img/header.png);
```